# how to retrieve back data from an html table that is created with php loop and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i have created a grid or some kind of table in html using Php and loop through MySQL to fill that table

PROBLEM IS : how to read this table's cell's data using JavaScript , i have tried it , but it returned all data in the tablebut i want to click on a cell and get its data

it is easy to read table cells ( if it was a normal table ) , but because of this damn loop . i can't . it just read everything , dose not understand when i'm clicking on an specific cell

my loop code :

```
echo "<table>" while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)   /*$res = $st->fetchObject()*/){//loop through the returned rows
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td id='{$tdid}'> $row->id </td> <td> $row->title </td> <td> $row->department </td><td> $row->position </td> <td> $row->email </td>";
echo"</tr>";
```

}

thank you beforehand

Comment: Please post code

Comment: Is it ok to use jquery or should be pure javascript?

Comment: everything , including jquery

Answer (score 0):

In order for javascript to determine which cell is being clicked, each td must have a unique id otherwise it doesn't know where to get it from.